# Multiline annotations in Json Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following Helm chart

```
metadata:                                                     
  ...
  annotations:                                                                                       
  {{- with $.Values.CP.annotations }}                         
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}                                 
  {{- end }}
```

In the values.yaml I have defined the following the annotations as json value strings:

```
CP:
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '[{"name":"macvlan-conf","interface":"myintf1"}]'
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '[{"name":"macvlan-conf2","interface":"myintf2"}]'
```

When I run helm template I see only the last one in the output.

```
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '[{"name":"macvlan-conf2","interface":"myintf2"}]'
  labels:
```

I dont see both the lines in the output. What am I doing wrong? I have tried with range as well but with no luck.

Any pointers/help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the map key is same for both annotations, it will print only once